# Remote MySQL not working in linux via cPanel

Tags: mysql, remote-server

I have a database server and an application server and trying to connect my application server the remote database server using PHP.

As usual I used the following way to it in the following manner.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("remotedb.com", "mysqladmin", "mysqlpassword") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
?>
```

But when I am trying to run this test I am getting the following error.

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Host 'gator418.hostgator.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server in /home/username/public_html/testmysql.php on line 2
Host 'gator418.hostgator.com' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

I have added the domain as %www.myappserver.com% to the remote server's cpanel "Remote MySQL" but still the issue persists. Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote database username is not allowed to connect using your host. Most probably it is set to only be able to connect from "localhost", so check the details of your username on your mysql server and see the list of allowed hosts

Comment: What must be the username in this case?

Comment: @lock when we create a new mysql user we also specify which hosts this user can connect from. So my guess is that the user you are trying is only allowed to connect via "localhost" which is default. So if you could edit that user to also be able to connect from your other domain that should then theoretically work

Comment: Is this all available for my cPanel?

Comment: im sure it must be but unfortunately im a webmin guy. im sure someone will guide us here

Comment: Okay, I will contact the hostgator team and see.

Answer (score 0):

Try this first from your local machine

```
$ mysql -h gator418.hostgator.com -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1130: Host '192.168.1.4' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

If you are getting above error do the below codes

Do this in your server.

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:

mysql> use mysql

mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* to mysqladmin@'gator418.hostgator.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysqlpassword'; 

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also, update firewall rules to make sure port# 3306 is open on the server that is running the mysql database.

After the above changes, when you try to connect to the mysql database from a remote client, you’ll not get the “Host is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server” error message anymore.

This can be achievable from Cpanel also. Grant all permission to the user you have created. (For the particular database you want)

Comment: Both systems can be accessed only by cPanel.

Comment: You don't have shell access ?

Comment: Try Granting all permission to that user from Cpanel.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have shell and I tried giving all permissions.